# Ascending central series for $D_8$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups

My Group Theory notes give as definition for an ascending series:

$G_0, G_1,...,G_n \unlhd G $ such that $\{1\} = G_0 \unlhd G_1 \unlhd ... \unlhd G_n=G$ and $G_{i+1}/ G_{i} \subset Z(G/G_{i})$. As an example the series for $D_8$ (dihedral group of order 8) is given:

$$\{1\} \unlhd Z(D_8) \unlhd D_8$$

I don't see how this satisfies the definition at all. Computing $Z(D_8/Z(D_8))$ gives you

$$Z(D_8/Z(D_8))=Z(D_8)/Z(D_8)= {1}\neq D_8/Z(D_8),$$

where we use that $Z(D_8) \subset Z(D_8)$ and the correspondence theorem. What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is that $Z(G/Z(G)) \neq Z(G)/Z(G)$. In your example, $D_8/Z(D_8)$ has order $4$, and therefore it is itself abelian (so its center is the whole group).

Comment: I see, thank you!